# How to find the value of gain K at which the root locus intersects with the imaginary axis

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Take a look at this closed loop system
$$
T(s) = \frac{-K(s+1)^2}{(1-K)s^2 + 2(1-K)s + (2-K)}
$$
The Routh Table is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s^2 & (1-K) & (2-K) \\
s^1 & 2(1-K) & 0 \\
s^0 &(2-K) & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now we search for a complete row of zeros that yields the possibility for imaginary axis roots. From the table, there are two values of $K$ namely 1,2 and both are positive. The only thing I can conclude from this table is the system is unstable $1<K<2$ but I can't determine the value of K at which the root locus intersects with the imaginary axis. Any suggestion how one can use Routh table in this case? Is this a case where Rough table fails?

Answer (score 0):

No need for Routh table because from

$$
(1-K)s^2+2(1-K)s+K-2=0
$$

we have

$$
s = \frac{-(K-1)\pm\sqrt{K-1}}{K-1}
$$

or calling $\zeta = K-1$ and assuming that $K > 0$

$$
s = \frac{-\zeta\pm\sqrt{\zeta}}{\zeta}
$$

and for $-1 < \zeta < 0$  both complex roots are inside the negative complex semiplane being stable. For $0\lt \zeta \lt 1$ the denominator has one root is inside the positive complex semiplane and the closed loop is unstable. Finally, for $1 < \zeta < \infty$ the system is stable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm asking if Routh table fails in this example. I can draw the conclusion about the stability using different methods.